# Require.js/Backbone.js: several views are using the same collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, frontend

at first I've to say that I'm not a frontend guy. ;) But in my leisure time I'm working with JS. Currently I'm working on a single page app which uses require.js and Backbone.js. I really like this both libraries!

To my problem:
I've a backbone collection which gets its information from the backend via the fetch() function. This collection only holds data which will not change. The information will be needed to describe a game unit which is defined in the backend. I need the collection for two backbone views, but it's not necessary to fetch the data again. It would be enough to fetch it once, but since I'm using require.js I've to create a new instance of this object. What is the "right" way to solve this problem? Singleton, global object? And I'll have more collections which only holds data which will not change during over the runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the collection will never change (i.e. the data on the cleitn won't be changed after being received form the server), simply provide the same collection instance to your various views.

Comment: Ok, but how to provide the instance? I could do it with a Singleton or store it somewhere global (e.g. window) would be a possibility as well.

Comment: That mainly depends on your preference: either is fine, but often you'll see the collection simply attached to the top-level application object (because the implementation is simpler than a singleton).

Comment: Ah okay. I didn't work with a top-level application object yet. Is that the right attitude?

Comment: Usually yes: it prevents you from polluting the namesapce with lots of variables. Instead you just have 1 variable for your application and put everything in there as (sub-)attributes.

Comment: Mhh... I don't have a lot of variables yet. Maybe it's because of the early state of my project. I thought I can handle it without a top-level app object. And I thought require.js helps me to work without this object.